# Hibernate Types framework throws "PSQLException: ERROR: cannot cast type bigint to interval" when using the PostgreSQLIntervalType with a native SQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate-types

I'm a beginner in the Spring Framework.

I'm using the hibernate-types for casting a PostgreSQL Interval into a Java Duration Object.

For selecting all rows this works fine. I've created a data model for the specific table and used the TypeDef annotation for the mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
@Typedef(
    typeClass = PostgreSQLIntervalType.class,
    defaultForType = Duration.class
)
@Getter @Setter
public class Test {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private Duration flightDuration;
}
```

But now I want to create a custom native query. I want to select all rows from table Test, where the flightDuration is a RequestParam of a webservice. 
Like this as a basic example (the real query is much more complex and needs some special postgres functions):

```
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<Test, int> {

    @Query( value = SELECT * FROM test t WHERE flight_duration = ?1 , nativeQuery = true )
    List<Test> findByFlightDuration(Duration flightDuration);

}
```

But here is my problem. I don't know how to use the PostgreSQLIntervalType for casting the Duration into a PostgreSQL Interval.

If i execute the query like the way above, i'll get the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot cast type bigint to interval
```

So where i have to set an annotation (or whatever) like the TypeCast in the Test Class, that the Duration will be casted into a PostgreSQLIntervalType?

Comment: Why using a native query?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reasonfor using a native query. You can simply JPQL.

```
@Query( value = "FROM test t WHERE flight_duration = ?1")
List<Test> findByFlightDuration(Duration flightDuration);
```

Comment: it doesn't work, too: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: interval = bigint. And as a mentioned, i need some postgres specific methods in the real query. This is only an example.

Comment: @user2622344 you should not use db specifica if using jpa.jpa is to abstract the underlaying db.

Answer (score 0):

If you REALLY need the nativeQery, because you need it, then you have to cast the integer in your query into an Interval of PostgreSQL.

I suppose you provide seconds in your query, and the `?1` is the number of seconds your flight will take.
Try the following:

```
@Query(value = SELECT * FROM test t WHERE flight_duration = (?1 || ' secs') , nativeQuery = true )
List<Test> findByFlightDuration(int flightDurationInSec);
```

More information here: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/Pine.LNX.4.44.0410051443550.13144-100000@matrix.gatewaynet.com

But I suggest you to review if you really need this or not. Maybe you can try with JPQL. Let us know.

Comment: Alternatively: `make_interval(secs => ?1)`

Answer (score 0):

For native SQL queries, you need to use the Hibernate-specific `setParameter` `Query` method to provide the Hibernate Type that's needed to handle custom column types:

```
List<Test> tests = entityManager.createNativeQuery("""
    SELECT * 
    FROM test t 
    WHERE flight_duration = :duration
    """, Test.class)
.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class)
.setParameter("duration", flightDuration, PostgreSQLIntervalType.INSTANCE)
.getResultList();
```

This way, Hibernate will know how to handle the `duration` query parameter.